# SQL query to merge tables and produce results

Tags: sql, oracle

**Person_Tbl**

```
PersonID |  Name
------------------
101      |  Stefan
102      |  Andreas
```

**PersonDescription_Tbl**

```
PDId | PersonId |  Desc   | Lang
---------------------------
1    | 101      | Hello  | en
2    | 101      | Hallo  | de 
3    | 102      | Hello  | en
4    | 102      | Hallo  | de
```

The output that I am looking for is to compare the above 2 tables and get me the result similar like shown below:

**Output**

```
Name    | Desc_en  | Desc_de
---------------------------
Stefan  | Hello    | Hallo
Andreas | Hello    | Hallo
```

I tried the following SQL sub queries but no luck. Please let me know if there is any query that will fetch the information similar to stated above.

```
Select * from Person_Tbl where PersonID in (Select PersonID from PersonDescription_Tbl)
```

Comment: Is `dec` a typo for `desc`?

Comment: Yes. I have corrected the name above in the table

Comment: Just as a bit of advice, Oracle identifiers (such as table names) are not case-sensitive (unless enclosed in double quotes `"`) so there's nothing gained by using mixed case. If one took a look at your data dictionary (say, by querying `DBA_TABLES`), he would see `PERSON_TBL` and `PERSONDESCRIPTION_TBL`.

Comment: Subash J, can you accept one of the answers below? @YogeshSharma answered first so he should get the credit IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the `joins` with *conditional* aggregation instead of going with `in`

```
select p.Name, max(case when pd.Lang = 'en' then pd.Dec end) as Desc_en,
               max(case when pd.Lang = 'de' then pd.Dec end) as Desc_de   
from Person_Tbl p
inner join PersonDescription_Tbl pd on pd.PersonId  = p.PersonId 
group by p.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the solution! It is working for me.

Comment: I have one more USECASE where if there is no entry available for a specific person in PersonDescription_Tbl (or) one entry is available specific to one language then it fails... Let me know if you have any solution regarding this case. In this case it should return the person name with other two columns null (or) existing values.

Comment: @SubashJ in that case you want to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is join your tables, then pivot the data, which you can do either with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.name, MAX(CASE WHEN pd.lang = 'en' THEN pd.desc END) AS desc_en
     , MAX(CASE WHEN pd.lang = 'de' THEN pd.desc END) AS desc_de
  FROM person_tbl p INNER JOIN persondescription_tbl pd
    ON p.personid = pd.personid;
```

if you don't mind using Oracle-specific syntax, you can use the `DECODE()` function and save yourself a few keystrokes:

```
SELECT p.name, MAX(DECODE(pd.lang, 'en', pd.desc)) AS desc_en
     , MAX(DECODE(pd.lang, 'de', pd.desc)) AS desc_de
  FROM person_tbl p INNER JOIN persondescription_tbl pd
    ON p.personid = pd.personid;
```

or with the `PIVOT` operator (if you're using 11g or above):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.name, pd.dec, pd.lang
      FROM person_tbl p INNER JOIN persondescription_tbl pd
        ON p.personid = pd.personid
) PIVOT (
    desc FOR lang IN ('en' AS desc_en, 'de' AS desc_de )
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you David.. I will try using DECODE()